# Jekyll templates/snippits/shortcuts

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I've been playing around with Jekyll for a couple of days, I've got a working site, but on many pages I want to use templates/snippits/shortcuts to make it easy to re-use commonly-typed content.

In MediaWiki, this is what I would have done;

```
This is a test {{ iconSmileFace }}
```

Where `{{ iconSmileFace }}` obviously translates to something like `<img src = "resources/images/smile.png" />`

I've seen that Jekyll has includes, so I could do `{{% include iconSmileFace.html %}}` but this syntax seems kinda verbose, and maybe not quite the Jekyll-way of doing things. Is there another better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a snippet to hold all of my icons whether they are images or svgs or font icons:

```
{% case include.icon %}
{% when 'smiley-face' %}
  Smiley face
{% when 'heart' %}
  Heart
{% when 'close' %}
  X
{% when 'next' %}
  >
{% endcase %}
```

Then include it where you need it `{% include icon.html icon="smiley-face" %}`

Comment: This is the closest to the solution I used. I went with `{% include iconSmile.htm %}` like syntax, as it's shorter to type every time.

Comment: I made a slight mistake, as the context is jekyll it would have been `{% case include.icon %}`

Comment: @xconspirisist I think that it's nice to have your syntax, I'm not a fan of having a file for every icon though.

Comment: As they're going to be used frequently, I thought it more important to reduce the amount of typing, and that's why ideally I would have liked something like `{{ iconSmileFace }}`, which I why I chose the above option. I thought about the large amount of small files in `_includes/`, but as the site is statically compiled, there is no performance impact to  people that browse the site, that's why I think it's acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

A good idea would be to define a [liquid tag](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#tags).

Create the `_plugins` directory and a file called `smile.rb` with this content:

```
module Jekyll
  class RenderSmileTag < Liquid::Tag

    def render(context)
      '<img src = "resources/images/smile.png" />'
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('smile', Jekyll::RenderSmileTag)
```

Then every time you want to render the image just use: `{% smile %}` and it will generate `<img src="resources/images/smile.png" />`

Comment: I feel this solution is over the top - having to right lots of boilerplate ruby code for every instance isn't going to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to output image tags with the shortcut, there's another way with a GitHub Pages supported plugin:

*(Though I haven't tested this myself)*

From the plugin `jemoji`'s [documentation](https://github.com/jekyll/jemoji#customizing), you can serve custom emojis by pointing to a custom source in your `_config.yml`:

```
emoji
  src: "/resources/images"
```

Then reference the emoji in your markdown document:

```
It's a beautiful day! :smile:
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution, but unfortunately I want to do more than just smiles.